# Setting passport jwt strategy for two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have API which have 2 collections - admins and users. Currently my passport jwtStrategy is:

```
const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwtPayload, done) => {
  console.log(jwtPayload)
  User.findById(jwtPayload.sub, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, null)
    }

    if (user) {
      return done(null, user)
    } else {
      return done(null, false)
    }
  })
})
```

however that's working only for users because findById is being done on users. I would need something like `findById here or here()`. How I can combine these two?

Comment: what do you mean by here or here? Admin or user?

Comment: yes, on two collections

Comment: Did you try my answer, did it work for you?

Comment: work in progress give me more time to check everything, to be honest I was thinking about same code as in your answer but just was carious is there something more suitable

Comment: There is no other way that you can check in multiple collection with just one query.

Comment: Can we chat for a second?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195739/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-bharti-and-dopecode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `user` exists in `User` collection or not, and if not, then you can check for the user in `Admin` collection.

Try this :

```
const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwtPayload, done) => {
  console.log(jwtPayload)
  User.findById(jwtPayload.sub, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err, null)
    }

    if (user) {
      return done(null, user)
    } else {
        //search in Admin collection
        Admin.findById(jwtPayload.sub,(err,admin) => {
            if(err){
                return done(err,null)
            }
            if(admin){
                return done(null,admin)
            }else{
                return done(null, false)
            }
        })
    }
  })
})
```